# I really need to delete all bookmarks in my xmarks account, how?

Tags: browser, bookmarks

How??
I have try everything on the web-based xmarks dashboard.

Don't wanna touch bookmarks which within browser right now.
Just wanna delete via xmarks itself.

THX!